# Trigger onclick when page is loaded

Tags: javascript

I have a set of radio buttons with an onclick event that hides/shows an area of the website.  The onclick also enables/disables spry validation.

The onclick is working great!  However, not sure how to trigger the onclick when the page is loaded and the radio button is marked as clicked.

For example, the user may select radio button on the main page.  Then later in the form process the user may want to edit the input that they put in.  I would then check the radio button that the user had selected on the main page.  Since the user has not clicked the radio button the hidden area still remains hidden.

Answer (score 0):

```
window.onready=function()
{    
    if(document.getElementById('yourRadioButtonId').checked) {
       //call your function, that you want to be triggered, as you will have the same call back function bounded for your onclick event    
}
```

or

```
window.onready=function()
    {    
        var radioButton=document.getElementById('yourRadioButtonId');
        if(radioButton.checked) {
           radioButton.click();
        }
    }
```

Note: Not not all browsers allow simulated events in this way. Please see the jQuery source  for the trigger method to see how all the browser quirks are handled.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to handle this is to write a helper function. Later, this helper function can be called by both of onClick (on radio button) and onLoad (on body element) events. This function will get the valu of your radio button and will do the stuff based on the result.

For example:

```
function handleRadioButtonStateAction() {
     var radioButtons = document.getElementsByName('theRadioButtonName');
     for (var x = 0; x < radioButtons.length; x ++) {
         if (x == yourDesiredButton && radioButtons[x].checked) {
             //do action
         }
   }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answers.  Still struggling on this.  Do the solutions offered, also send the value of the checked radio button.  My call function depends on the value to work.

Comment: As I told you in my answer, your event handler (like the one that I wrote the implementation) should not depend on getting the value of radio button as an argument. You can easily extract the value of radio button in the method (by calling document.getElementsByName if you deal with a group of radio buttons or document.getElementById if you have a single radio button). This way, you can use the handler implementation for both of onClick (on radio button) and onLoad (on body element) events.